# C# class design issue

Tags: c#, oop

Right now I have a wrapper class which contains around 10 methods out of which 8 methods provides functionality for ClassA & 2 methods provides functionality for ClassB so I am planning to instantiate ClassA and ClassB in the wrapper class constructor to use them in the appropriate methods.

Is this design fine or am I missing something? I know one drawback with this approach is the calling app will receive an exception if the user passes the wrong constructor parameter and uses the wrong methods.

See sample code below:

```
Public class Wrapper
{
ClassA _a = null;
ClassB _b = null;

public Wrapper(bool createClassA)
{
  if (createClassA)
  {
     _a = new ClassA();
  }
  else
  {
     _b = new ClassB();
  }
}

public string Method1()
{
   return _a.ReturnSomething();
}

//similarly Method2 to Method8 calls _a class methods.

public void Method9()
{
   return _b.DoSomething();
}

public string Method10()
{
   return _b.ReturnTestMessage();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of having conditional initialization in the cstor?

Comment: This... seems wrong.  Do you know how to use interfaces?

Comment: no this design is not fine..... why are you doing this?

Comment: I believe that this question is best suited at code review.

Comment: This may be wrong I want to know which is the proper way to have two classes wrapped inside a single class.

Comment: Your code lends itself to a whole bunch of `NullReferenceException`s at runtime.

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs: I cannot use interface here since classA and classB have different functionalities.

Comment: @user972255 The proper way is to instantiate everything that the object requires so that its public interface (its methods and its properties, in other words) is reliable and does not throw exceptions under non-exceptional circumstances. If this doesn't satisfy you, then please give us more details on the bigger picture and we might help you with another approach.

Comment: Why not have two wrapper classes, one for each type?

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: You mean I need to create the appropriate class in each & every method?

Comment: @user972255 If it makes sense semantically for your `Wrapper` to always contain the two objects, then leave your code as it is but remove the conditional. If it doesn't make sense, then you'll have to create an abstract `Wrapper` class and, from it, derive two specialized wrapper subclasses, one for each type of object you were wrapping.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: Actually, classes A and B are distinct but the client app already refers to an interface (which was referring to class A previously) but now we want to add the class B functionalities as well.

Comment: @user972255 create a secondary wrapper instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have two classes that don't call any common functions.  Putting them in a wrapper class doesn't make much sense since the two classes do completely different things.

If the classes are conceptually linked (you think of these classes together) then perhaps putting them in a namespace would make more sense?

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    class ClassA
    {
        // ...
    }

    class ClassB
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, classes A and B are in the same namespace. Can you please tell me clearly what I need to?

Answer (score 2):

The way you have wrapped two classes together is fine ( ish ), however the way you have made it conditional that only 1 of the classes is instantiated is not ok.  The wrapper class should be transparently usable.  Meaning that you can call any method on the wrapper class without knowing about A or B or how it was constructed.

If classes A and B are distinct, then I'd question whether you need to wrap them at all.  Unless perhaps if your wrapper class is some kind of Facade or Adapter.

Comment: Yes, classes A and B are distinct but the client app already refers to an interface (which was referring to class A previously) but now we want to add the class B functionalities as well.

Comment: what I don't understand is why you don't let them create the classes themselves? you put it on them to pass a boolean the makes either of the classes inside the wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty generic code, so it's difficult to advise you. What benefit do you feel this wrapper provides your users?

The one concrete concern you have about using methods for the incorrect construction can be resolved by storing `createClassA` and checking inside your methods, or by checking _b or _a against null in each of the `method_X_` methods.

Alternately, it may be better for your wrapper to explicitly throw Exceptions if the caller invokes the "incorrect" wrapped methods rather than returning nothing at all, or null, or an empty string (etc.)